# Is there any way to use NPM and not Yarn while creating a project with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have both Yarn and NPM installed but whenever I try to create-react-app it automatically uses Yarn.

I tried to run `create-react-app app --use-npm` but then it created it using an older version of node and NPM.

I then tried updating the node and NPM version and ran `npm -v` which showed the latest version but again after running `create-react-app app --use-npm` it got created with older versions devoid of latest features of the create-react-app.

I want to use NPM and create the react app using all the latest versions of node and NPM without removing Yarn from my system. Where I am going wrong and what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use `npm`, go to the project folder:

1. Delete `yarn.lock`
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Run `npm install`

It will use the latest `npm` installed **on yours system**.

Answer (score 0):

Try `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: running  "npx create-react-app my-app" created the app with yarn and not with npm. I wanted to use npm for this.

Comment: Try to remove yarn and then create-react-app with npm.